# How do I check if the images are already in the memory before they are saved again?

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I noticed when optimizing the performance of my app the Glide must check whether the image is already in cache. Now comes the trick in the matter.

*How does it work?*

With the code below, I would always save the image again at the start of the classe and load.

**So:**

```
    Glide.with(mContext).load(Objects.requireNonNull(user).getImageurl()).donloadOnly(new SimpleTarget <File>(){
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(File resource, GlideAnimation<? super File> glideAnimation){
            OGGER.debug("Photo downloaded");

            }
    });

Glide.with(mContext).load(Objects.requireNonNull(user).getImageurl()).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).into(image_profile);
```

**or:**

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(Objects.requireNonNull(user).getImageurl()).donloadOnly(new SimpleTarget <File>(){
    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(File resource, GlideAnimation<? super File> glideAnimation){
        OGGER.debug("Photo downloaded");

        Glide.with(mContext).load(Objects.requireNonNull(user).getImageurl()).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).into(image_profile);
        }
});
```

Thx. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they mention on their DOCS:

By default, Glide checks multiple layers of caches before starting a new request for an image:

1. Active resources - Is this image displayed in another View right now?
2. Memory cache - Was this image recently loaded and still in memory?
3. Resource - Has this image been decoded, transformed, and written to the disk cache before?
4. Data - Was the data this image was obtained from written to the disk cache before?

I highly recommend you to read it.
https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html#caching-in-glide

To load the image into `ivImg` (your ImageView) you just need to do the following:

```
Glide.with(context)
.load("http://via.placeholder.com/300.png")
.into(ivImg);
```

Comment: Thank you my friend. I also read that earlier. I was surprised that no if query should be written. Does he put the picture in the `public void onResourceReady` in the `ImageView`?

Comment: Not sure I understood the question, can you clarify?

Comment: I have change the DOCS. Is the approach correct as described above?

Comment: @Takethepain check the answer above, I've updated it with more info.